# MySQL query For Arrival of stock transaction

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database filled with stock transactions, and I am trying to calculate the arrival. The given formula is

> Arrival: (Sum of (AvgExecPrice - ArrivalPrice) * Shares * SideIndicator / Value * 10000) * -1

but I cant formulate this in an SQL query. I keep getting wrong results. Here is my query, what am I doing wrong? Assuming I have columns in a table called `AvgExecPrice`, `ArrivalPrice`, `Shares`, `SideIndicator` and `Value`.

```
select sum((AvgExecPrice - ArrivalPrice) * Shares * SideIndicator / value * 10000) * -1 
from support;
```

Comment: What results are you getting? What are you expecting?  Could you give us an example with data?

Comment: Have Associativity in Mind,  for * Shares * SideIndicator / Value * 10000

Comment: For example when I do it for total which is all the transactions in the table I get a 1234.093 when I am suppose to get -32.49. Should I assume that each transaction has its own Arrival Price?

Answer (score 0):

If above given formula is really correct then you got just problem with brackets
Then following should work try it without brackets like this.

```
select sum(AvgExecPrice - ArrivalPrice) * Shares * SideIndicator / value * 10000 * -1
```